# ruby hash tree with blocks

Tags: ruby, tree, dsl, block

how can I do this:

```
class MyClass

   tile 'some title'

   collection do
    node1 'node1'
    node2 'node2'

      another_collection do
        node1 'node1'
        node2 'node2' 
      end
   end
   end_node 'some text'

end
```

and produce following:

```
MyClass.build #=>{:title=>'some title',:collection=>{:node1=>'node1',:node2=>'node2',:another_collection=>{:node1=>'node1',:node2=>'node2'}},:end_node=>'some text'}
```

What i was trying is to make simple DSL and build hash tree. I'm sure that can be done with method_missing and instance_eval, but i don't now how to build that logic.

Thanks for help

Comment: What have you tried so far? For start, try to handle just first-level method calls, i.e. first cover usage without blocks.

Comment: Mladen,thanks for answer..It's trivial to create first nodes and blocks. just in method_missing merge hash with method names...problem is to create deep nested tree nodes...

Answer (score 8):

In your `method_missing`, you should check if a block is given, and, if so, recursively call the main method with it:

```
class HashBuilder

  def self.build &block
    hb = HashBuilder.new
    hb.instance_eval(&block)
    hb.hash
  end

  attr_reader :hash

  def initialize
    @hash = {}
  end

  def method_missing meth, *args, &block
    @hash[meth] = block ? HashBuilder.build(&block) : args.first
  end
end

p HashBuilder.build{
  a :b
  c :d
  e do
    f :g
  end
}
#=> {:a=>:b, :c=>:d, :e=>{:f=>:g}}
```